# Rewrite folders and Remove the trailing slash at the end

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to have only one URL without the trailing slash at the end of the URLs/folders, but at the same time I want to re-write this folder to use dynamic pages, for example:

if I have:

```
mydomain.com/folder
mydomain.com/folder/
```

and

```
mydomain.com/folder/second
mydomain.com/folder/second/
```

then I want to open only "mydomain.com/folder" and "mydomain.com/folder/second" and this URLs should open a dynamic pages. This is what I am trying, but it does not work, it crash my page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$   /$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    includes/category.php?url=$1&pageType=category [L] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$  /$1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$   includes/subcategory.php?url=$1&pageType=subCategory [L]
```

What am I doing wrong? can you help me to run the right syntax  please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect the trailing slash URL's instead of just rewriting them. You also probably need to add some conditions to the rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /includes/category.php?url=$1&pageType=category [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /includes/category.php?url=$1&pageType=subCategory [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/?$    includes/category.php?url=$1&pageType=category [L] 

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/?$   includes/subcategory.php?url=$1&pageType=subCategory [L]
```

you may also add the following conditions (before rewrites) to exclude real file and folders from those rule:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```